# Resharper 2016.1 Formatting method documentation header (XML Doc Comments)

Tags: c#, resharper, xml-documentation

I'm trying to get Resharper to reformat my XML doc comments in a certain way. I want the summary text on a new line, but other tags on a single line. Which is the same format as the Visual Studio placeholder text (when `///` is entered).

I've searched StackOverflow and haven't been able to find anything yet.

If my explanation hasn't been clear enough, this is what I mean:

Before cleanup:

```
/// <summary>This is a summary</summary>
/// <param name="object">An object</param>
```

After cleanup (currently):

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="object">
/// An object
/// </param>
```

After cleanup (desired):

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="object">An object</param>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Failing that, is there a way to populate the Visual Studio placeholder text with the summary text Resharper generates?

(I've posted this question on the Resharper forums, but haven't had a response yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that this is currently possible in Resharper. It can be done using the [Agent Smith](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.AgentSmith/) plugin, as suggested by Jeremy Morton on [my Resharper Support post](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207558025-Formatting-method-documentation-header-XML-Doc-Comments-).

To do this:

1. Install Agent Smith
2. In Resharper options, under AgentSmith => Xml Documentation => Reflow And Retag

   - Set `<summary>` to 'Always'
   - Set everything else to 'Never'
3. Save your changes.

This can be done on an individual comment, by opening the quick fix window (Ctrl + .) and choosing 'Reflow & Retag Comment [Agent Smith]'.

It can also be set up to make changes to a whole file - during Code Cleanup - by choosing the 'Reflow & Retag XML Documentation Comments' and 'Reflow XML Documentation Comments' options.